# Where is the elusive MSBuild Project File Creation Wizard in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, msbuild, continuous-integration

I'd like to create a TFS build project without having to learn how to manually create TFS build project files.  Are there any wizards in Visual Studio 2010 to do so?

According to the [Visual Studio 2008 documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181716%28v=VS.90%29.aspx), there's a "MSBuild Project File Creation Wizard" that you can launch.  And according to the [Visual Studio 2010 documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd647547.aspx), there should be a "Process" tab where you can specify which projects you want to build.  I don't see either option in Visual Studio 2010, either a wizard I can run or a "Process" tab in a build definition.  The only tabs present for me are:

```
General
Trigger
Workspace
Build Defaults
Project File
Retention Policy
```

Why am I not seeing basic support for creating TFS build projects?  Are there any workarounds for me?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looks like you're connected to a TFS 2008 server from VS 2010. You'll need to be connected to TFS 2010 in order to see the "Process" tab. And, correspondingly, you'll need to use VS 2008 to see the MSBuile Project File Creation Wizard against your TFS 2008 server.

Another option is to install [Team Explorer 2008](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=0ed12659-3d41-4420-bbb0-a46e51bfca86&displaylang=en). That's a free download you can use to edit build definitions on TFS 2008 servers (among other things, of course). I'd also recommend installing [TFS 2008 SP1](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=9e40a5b6-da41-43a2-a06d-3cee196bfe3d) after installing Team Explorer 2008.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not in charge of the TFS setup; are there any workarounds that you know of?

Comment: @Jacob - Learning the language of your build tools is worth the effort.